# Material to use for computer system cover against UV and salty air?

Tags: usb, static-discharge

I live right next to the sea and have a large window quite close to my computer setup which allows a lot of indirect sunlight to enter.

I'd like to buy or make a cover for my computer system. From visiting my usual mom & pop computer shop yesterday I got the impression these might not really exist any more.

If I make my own I need a material with these qualities;

- Block or reduce ultraviolet light which can de-polymerize plastics (the sun here in Australia is much stronger than in the northern hemisphere).
- Block salt-laden sea air which can oxidize USB and other connectors.
- Not cause static electricity when covering or uncovering.
- Keep dust off of course

My setup is a laptop plugged into a wide-screen LCD with a few external drives. So I think I'd want a largish sheet to flop over the whole desk.

Are such covers commonly sold these days? What material(s) should I look for which provides the listed attributes?

USB connectors of various ages showing differing degrees of oxidation or corrosion:
[image: corroded USB connectors]

Comment: Glass shields against UV. That is one thing you do not have to worry about unless you open the window.

Comment: Actually it's a very small room so I leave the window open with just a fly screen most of the time for fresh air unless it's raining or cold.

Comment: Not clear -- is this for the system while it's operating, or when it's powered off?  If the latter I'd just make (or have my wife make) a "slip cover" for the system, using "outerwear" fabric of some sort.

Comment: Has this actually been a problem? I've never really had an issue with tropical weather and living next to the sea

Comment: All the USB ports and one USB stick got oxidised on my previous laptop enough that connections became unreliable when I lived on a Mexican beach for half a year. Oxidization is now just visible on a couple of my current USB devices after spending two summers in a tent on a beach. I'll try to include a photo... Now I'm back in Australia I've got a room over the sea again. In Mexico all of my friends computers had died from the salt in the air and here iron and steel fittings on buildings don't last long. An Amiga 4000 I once owned suffered from too much sun in a less sunny room than this one.

Comment: Really your only solution is to place a air oxidizer in your room and purchase a window ac unit for additional filter protection.  You need to filter the UV isn't that big of a problem, easy enough to resolve that, purchase uv protection blinds.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ouch I can't afford that, plus it's not my window (room comes with my job working at reception in a backpacker hostel!) but thanks anyway (-:

Comment: @hippietrail - I am sure you can request blinds for your window.  You can find air oxidizers for very reasonable prices.  You need something to filter the air.

Comment: Could you get a rugged water-tight box, cut a small hole (which you could then seal with some silicon) and have a USB hub in there that you only open when you need to (to protect your USB memory sticks), bigger devices could you get some rubber caps for the USB plugs so that [when they're not in use] the contacts are protected? USB sockets can also have rubber covers that you insert and remove as and when you need...?

Comment: You live next to the sea and your sitting inside playing on your computer?  UV is an easy problem, just locate the computer out of direct sunlight.  Salt air is a problem.  A hermetically sealed enclosure, like BigChris describes, is really the direction you need to go except you having cooling issues.  You could try to make silicone rubber (Sugru/Oogoo) "jackets" to seal exposed metal parts.  Some military or industrial grade equipment may stand up better.  Or the opposite approach: go cheap and disposable, and replace when needed.